# SharePoint Build Number vs Version?

Tags: version, build-number

Having a “compatibility range mismatch between the Web server and database” you need to run the PSConfig upgrade command to get the content database at the same level as config database. And you typically run:

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait
```

The –inplace parameter specify whether to use version to version (v2v) upgrade or build to build (b2b. This can be quite confusing since when we look at our Configuration database version in the Servers in Farm page in Central administration (/_admin/FarmServers.aspx) it specifies a build number.

[image]

From the article [Software updates overview for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806329.aspx#terms) one can read:

> In SharePoint 2013, for build-to-build upgrades, you can use either in-place or database-attach methods. For version-to-version upgrade, only database-attach is supported. For more information about version-to-version upgrade, see [Overview of the upgrade process to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483.aspx). For an overview of the steps for in-place and database-attach upgrade for build-to-build upgrades, see [Install a software update (SharePoint 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806338.aspx)

So my guess is that `–inplace b2b` is the only option you have in an existing farm where you haven’t used a database attach method. Still I’m confused of the terminology used. Is a version the same as build numbers, or what is the difference?

## References

- [PSConfig command-line reference (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093(v=office.14).aspx)
- [SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers and CU's](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx)
- Todd Klindt's [SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346)
- [SharePoint Server 2013 Version Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erica/archive/2013/05/30/sharepoint-server-2013-version-reference.aspx)

Comment: As far as I think, Version number refers to the SharePoint version like 14 for SharePoint 2010, 15 for SharePoint 2013 etc. And build number is the build within that Version, as we know they increase the build number with the cumulative updates and service packs.

Comment: So 15 is the Version and 4420 is the Build..

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri So the -inplace v2v really means that you upgrade a content database from version 14 to version 15, and the b2b specifies that you upgrade content database from build 4727 to 4745? If you have a reference, please add this as an answer and I'll be happy to mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I think it is what you said, don't have any reference though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found an article [here](http://blog.fpweb.net/what-sharepoint-version-am-i-using/#.VfEt-vntlBc).

"What may seem obvious is actually more difficult to determine than you’d expect. Finding your version will depend on what operating system SharePoint is installed on and what build you are running, plus they all store the version information in separate places."

[image]

I checked my SharePoint 2013 for Administrators [Offical Book](https://www.microsoft-press.de/katalog/mspress/b%FCcher/deutsch/~/sharepoint/sharepoint%20server/?aktiv=1). There you can find the most official answer I found yet (Got the book in German):

[image]

I tried to translate as much as I can. Sorry, my english isn't the best:

**SharePoint Patching**
The following background information are for a better understanding of SharePoint patching and versioning.

**Understand SharePoint Versionnumbers**
The SharePoint Versionnumber is made up of four segments. The segments are shown in the following picture (Picture 8.13)

- The first segment ist the version. 12 stands for SP 2007, 14 for SP 2010 and 15 for SP2013
- The second segment is the subversionnumber. The number can increase due to Service Packs.
- The third segment is the exact SharePoint version. After installing patches and upgrades, the number will increase.
- The fours segment identifies the type of upgrade. There are differences:

  -5000 are a fully supported Hotfixs

  -1000 are Service Packs

  -300x are individual upgrades

Hope it helped, if so, please give it a "vote up" or mark it as answer.